# EditText is always returning a null value

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

When i'm calling my `editText` it returns a `Null` value
 My code is here:

```
public class LogIn extends Activity {

EditText userNameEditor;

EditText passwordEditor;

SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

userNameEditor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);

passwordEditor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordEditor);

preferences = getSharedPreferences(User.KEY_FOR_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

userNameEditor.setHint(preferences.getString(User.KEY_FOR_USERNAME, ""));

}   

}
```

I think  keep getting a nullPointerException is it because i'm calling setHint in onCreate?

NOTE: thanks everyone for the help. what it was, was i accidentally put in a previous id of the userNameEditor(i changed it) so the one in findViewById and android:id were different lol. never forget to check the little things i suppose

Comment: No, it's because your not inflating a layout.

Comment: could you show us your entire onCreate method?

Comment: @RodrigoHenriques yeah one sec

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call `setContentView()` before trying to find any views with `findViewById()`, and of course make sure there is actually a view of the correct type and with the correct ID in the layout.

Comment: i already have ;/ when i remove the editTextVar.setHint() then it runs properly ;(

Comment: @Bryan If you are calling setContentView(R.layout.something) as the first thing you do (before finding views), then findViewById() is returning null. This happens if it doesn't find a view with that id in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

call this method in your `OnCreate()` method

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

above this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess one: There is no *R.id.editTextUserName* at the XML that you are inflating.

Two: you are not setting the content view

Answer (score 0):

If this is your complete code you are missing the call to

```
setContentView(R.<your_activity_layout>)
```

so try

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.<layout>);

    editTextVar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(User.Key_FOR_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

    editTextVar.setHint(preferences.getString(User.KEY_FOR_USERNAME, ""));
}
```